# How to manually set the toggle state of wxpython platebutton

Tags: menu, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am building an application using platebutton iin wxpython. The problem is that I am not able to manually SetState of the toogle buton. I used SetState(0) but it does not change the state of toggle button. Any help would be great. Thanks. Sample code:

```
self.infinity= platebutton.PlateButton(self._ribbon,wx.ID_NEW, bmp = wx.Bitmap('infinity.bmp'), pos = (0,0), size = (38,18), style= platebutton.PB_STYLE_NOBG |platebutton.PB_STYLE_TOGGLE)

def OnInfinityToggled(self,event):
    if event.GetEventObject().IsPressed():
        self.popupmenu = wx.Menu()
        Session = self.popupmenu.Append(-1, "Session")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.SessionMenu, Session)
        self.PopupMenu(self.popupmenu,(2,23))
    else:
        pass

def SessionMenu(self, event):
    print 5
    self.infinity.SetState(0)
    self.infinity.Raise()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PLATE_NORMAL = 0
PLATE_PRESSED = 1
PLATE_HIGHLIGHT = 2
```

SetState(0) means set to normal.

Comment: I have already done that as you can see in my code above. But it does not work. Could  you please try the code and check whether it works or not because it is not working for me.

Comment: Could you please try with SetState(1) or SetState(2) to see if there is any different?

Comment: @user3248521 Or you can provide a demo that we can run and check what happend.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I managed to `toggle` state:

```
btn._ToggleState()
btn._pressed = True
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Playing around I managed to resolve my problem with

```
button._SetState(ix)
button.Refresh()
```

where ix = your choice of state.

Comment: I tried this but it is not working. After user toggles the button to pressed state, I want it to come back to normal state when user clicks anywhere in the window. But using above code it is not working..